# Screened periodic Coulomb interaction in 2D

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, coulombs-law

In this article

https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.09634

in equation (33), the authors propose a periodic screened Coulomb potential that is just of the form

$$ V(r) = \sum_{\gamma \in \mathbb{Z}^2}  \delta(r - \gamma_1 L_1 - \gamma_2 L_2)$$

where $L_1,L_2$ are two lattice vectors.

I wonder if there is a canonical more smoothed out version of this potential in 2D. More precisely, I wonder if there is a periodic $V$ describing the Coulomb interaction in 2D that is less singular than this $\delta$-potential.

If one just sums translates of the $\log$ potential, then this does not decay rapidly enough for the sum to converge, so I wonder if there are alternative choices available?

Comment: Two dimensional Kronig-Penney etc. like in here https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.06851?